# Original ArrayList changes when I use new operator

Tags: java

I run into a problem. The result is updated while I try to change the temp in the following code( I did nothing on the result):

```
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.add(new ArrayList<>());
List<List<Integer>> temp = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<Integer> list: result) {
    list.add(10000);
    temp.add(new ArrayList(list));
}
```

I do not know why the result turns out to be [[10000]] as well as the temp. Is there anything wrong with the add method like temp.add(new ArrayList(list))?

Answer (score 0):

The code, as written, only loops once. Let's take a look:

```
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.add(new ArrayList<>());
```

This initializes `result`, which is a `List`, whose elements are `List<Integer>`. You then add one element to result, so `result` is a single-element list. That one element is itself a zero-element list.

```
List<List<Integer>> temp = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here, you initialize `temp` to also be a `List` containing `List<Integer>` as its element type, but it's empty.

```
for (List<Integer> list: result) {
    list.add(10000);
    temp.add(new ArrayList(list));
}
```

Note that here, `result` only has one element. That one element is the thing you gave it on line 2, with `result.add(new ArrayList<>());`. This loop will iterate for each element of `result`, which will cause it to only loop once, because `result` only has one element.

When this happens, the first element of `result` will be updated to be a list containing `10000` rather than an empty list. So `result` will still be a singleton list, but its one element will now also be a singleton list containing `10000`.

You then call `temp.add(new ArrayList(list))`. Calling `new ArrayList(list)` creates an `ArrayList` that contains all the elements that `list` does. When you call it, `list` is a singleton containing `10000`, so the `new ArrayList(list)` is also a singleton containing just the number `10000`. Then, you add that `ArrayList` to `temp`, which was previously an empty list. Now, `temp` is a singleton, and its one element is a singleton list containing `10000`.

At this point, `result` and `temp` are both lists containing exactly one element, each of which is a list containing exactly one element, which is the number `10000`. That's why `result` and `temp` have the value `[[10000]]`, where `[10000]` is a list containing just the number `10000`, and `[[10000]]` is a list containing just `[10000]`.